# Telerik Kendo Diagram Layout Grid

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, grid, telerik, diagram

I am working on my kendo diagram in my angularjs projekt. I want to set a layout grid in the background as a guide for alligning the shapes. I did some research but could not find any solution.

Is something like this possible:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the Angular implementation but I've modified the jQuery version to include a grid that I use. https://dojo.telerik.com/OnoQIbix

This should get the grid on the diagram.

[image: Diagram with a grid]

Comment: Hi @Mart_ , thank you for your code snippet. I was able to insert your code into mine and have to tweek some minor changes. But it works. Thank you very much. In Germany we say "Kuss bruder" <3